# Prisma inserting null value for foreign key on a one-on-one relation

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma2

Relevant schema parts.

```
model ShopifyOfflineStoreSession {
  pk          String    @id(map: "PK_d371917bab72a48d6cce7880fc5") @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  id          String    @unique(map: "UQ_91ede9e23efbd7ee27b37bdd9ba") @db.VarChar
  store       Store?    @relation(fields: [pk], references: [shopifyOfflineSessionPk], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade, map: "FK_901a837fbbf20119aded3682f90")

  @@map("shopify_store_session")
}


model Store {
  id                       Int                         @id(map: "PK_f3172007d4de5ae8e7692759d79") @default(autoincrement())
  shopifyOfflineSessionPk  String?                     @unique(map: "UQ_901a837fbbf20119aded3682f90") @db.Uuid
  shopifyOfflineSession    ShopifyOfflineStoreSession?

  @@map("store")
}
```

This query fails:

```
await this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.create({
        data: {
          ...session,
          store: { connect: { id: store.id } },
        },
      });
```

Error:

```
2022-06-10 16:41:02.035 UTC [15541] ERROR:  null value in column "pk" violates not-null constraint
2022-06-10 16:41:02.035 UTC [15541] DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, offline_subbooks2.myshopify.com, 2022-06-10 16:41:02.033, 2022-06-10 16:41:02.033, null, subbooks2.myshopify.com, 005148992241858, f, null, null, null).
2022-06-10 16:41:02.035 UTC [15541] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "public"."shopify_store_session" ("pk","id","createdAt","updatedAt","shop","state","isOnline") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING "public"."shopify_store_session"."pk"
Issue saving Shopify offline token. Err: PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.create()` invocation in
/usr/src/api/src/store/store.service.ts:576:52
   573     data: session,
   574   });
   575 } else {
→  576   await this.prisma.shopifyOfflineStoreSession.create(
  Null constraint violation on the fields: (`pk`)
    at cb (/usr/src/api/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:38683:17) {
  code: 'P2011',
  clientVersion: '3.6.0',
  meta: { constraint: [ 'pk' ] }
}
query: DELETE FROM "store" WHERE "id" IN ($1) -- PARAMETERS: [18]
```

I don’t understand why prisma is setting `pk` on `shopifyOfflineStoreSession` to null. Can someone help me understand what’s causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#required-and-optional-1-1-relation-fields) state:

> In a one-to-one relation, the side of the relation without a relation scalar (the field representing the foreign key in the database) must be optional.

For me, I wanted a `Store` record to be able to exist without a `ShopifyOfflineStoreSession` which means I have to put the `relation scalar` on `ShopifyOfflineStoreSession` instead of `Store`.

This is how the final state looks now and there's no issues:

```
model Store {
  id                       Int                         @id(map: "PK_f3172007d4de5ae8e7692759d79") @default(autoincrement())
  shopifyOfflineSession    ShopifyOfflineStoreSession?
  
  @@map("store")
}

model ShopifyOfflineStoreSession {
  pk          String    @id(map: "PK_d371917bab72a48d6cce7880fc5") @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  id          String    @unique(map: "UQ_91ede9e23efbd7ee27b37bdd9ba") @db.VarChar
  store       Store     @relation(fields: [storeId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade, map: "FK_901a837fbbf20119aded3682f90")
  storeId     Int       @unique

  @@map("shopify_store_session")
}
```

I had to execute a few migrations to achieve this:

- create `storeId` (nullable) in `ShopifyOfflineStoreSession`
- add appropriate ids from `Store` to it
- make `storeId` non null
- change FK from `Store` to `ShopifyOfflineStoreSession`
- drop original FK (`shopifyOfflineSessionPk`) from `Store`.

If you want more details on these migration, ask in a comment.